# Using ASP.NET Core authorize attribute with SPA and AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc, authorize-attribute

We have an application that is using AngularJS on the client side and ASP.NET MVC Core on the server side. We are mostly using the ASP.NET MVC API and only have simple MVC Views that use Angular to load the different html/js views. In legacy full ASP.NET MVC apps we would put [Authorize] attributes on the controllers for the chtml Views and the redirect would happen to the Login page and then back using the ReturnURL.

In this app, let's say we have an /accounts/review page.  The Accounts controller exists but the review page is a SPA page that is handled by Angular.  If I put the [Authorize] attribute on the Accounts controller and try to hit the /accounts/review page, the Authorize attribute is triggered by the Accounts controller, and redirected to the Login page.  However, the ReturnUrl is not the full RawURL, it is just the '/accounts' url (without the /review).  Instead, I want the ReturnUrl to have the full URL, including the piece of the URL that is "handled" by AngularJS.

In older versions, you could create your own custom attribute that could change the way the Authorize attribute is handled.  I've also read where you can return an Unauthorized response instead and then have AngularJS handle the redirecting to the Login page.

Is there a simple solution to this that I'm missing? I feel like somewhere I should be able to override how the /accounts authorization is handled and inject a different return URL, but I'm not sure where that would go in the pipeline.